# place responsive menu link on nav bar instead of moving top-left in magento-2

Tags: magento2, menu, navigation

[image]I wanted to display the menu in the nav bar when it becomes responsive. But defaultly it gets displayed in top left with three lines. I wanted to replace this three lines with a text and also wanted to place this link on the nav bar itself.Can any on help .

thanks in advance

[image]
the default is as on left side but i want something like on left side

Comment: the three lines displayed in top left is called hamburger menu. This the standard way of displaying responsive menu. However you can still put text instead of 3 lines in vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\header\logo.phtml(you need to override this file in custom theme/module) and add/remove some css

Comment: can U explain how should I do.. I am just a beginner

Comment: I have answered how to change three lines to text, please wait for the 2nd answer " keeping the link on nav bar itself" till try first one . thanks

Comment: Check updated answer to keeping the link on nav bar itself. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the standard way of displaying responsive menu. However you can still put text instead of 3 lines in

`vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\hea‌​der\logo.phtml`

Override the file in your theme like this:

```
app\design\frontend\Vendor\themename\Magento_Theme\templates\html\header\logo.phtml
```

and edit the code like this:

```
<span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Your Text') ?></span></span>
```

and add this css:

```
 .nav-toggle {
        font-size: inherit;
    }
    .nav-toggle::before{
        content: "";
    }
    .nav-toggle > span{
          position: relative;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Changing Three lines/bar to text**

1) In your extended theme inside magento_theme module as below make some edit in logo.phtml

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml
```

There is a line

```
<span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Toggle Nav') ?></span></span>
```

Write your Text at place of Toggle Nav

```
<span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Store Menu') ?></span></span>
```

2) CSS Updates in your _extend.less under below path

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

Update below classes with following styles or more as you need you can

```
.nav-toggle > span{
   width:auto;
   height:auto;
   clip:unset;
}
.nav-toggle{
   font-size:14px;
}
.nav-toggle::before{
   display:none;
}
```

**Keep the menu link on nav bar**

Cut the above code we changed to display text instead of three bars

```
<span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Store Menu') ?></span></span>
```

Paste this code to sections.phtml under this path

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/sections.phtml
```

Now update above CSS

```
.nav-toggle{
   font-size:14px;
   position:relative;
   top:0;
}
```

I hope this will help you out, let me know if any problem

Run upgrade/deploy/cache commands to see CSS changes

Thanks

Comment: menu appears..! but clicking on menu does not show any action? pop up is not working.. why??

Comment: why are we putting the code on section.phtml??

Comment: please share your site URL to investigate the issue . Thanks

Comment: Nav bar lies in "sections container" so to place   menu link in nav bar we place it sections. By defaults it comes in "header content " container